# What is this string doing?

Tags: android, string, string-formatting

I was looking at the widget sample in the google api demos, and i found this line in the strings.xml

```
<string name="appwidget_text_format"><xliff:g id="prefix">%1$s</xliff:g></string>
```

and I don't understand what it's doing, I've never seen something like this, can someone please explain to me what's going on here.

I mean the whole, xliff:g and id, and especially the "%1$s". What's it doing?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xliff` here is an additional namespace (should be specified in the xml header) and refers to the [XML Localisation Interchange File Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLIFF).

The `%1$s` is a placeholder for a value you can later set in your Activity using the [getString(int resId, Object... arg)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a way to reference a string that is passed in as an argument. Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) in the **Formatting strings** where they give an example using it. Similarly you can do %2$d to reference a decimal.

Answer (score 1):

You better refer [how to use Formatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html) to get more understanding on "%1$s" part.